# How to check if request type is JSON in a Sinatra app?

Tags: sinatra

I need to parse a request body as JSON, but how do I check if the request is a JSON request?

Answer (score 1):

Provided you set `Content-Type: application/json` in the request:

```ruby
if request.content_type == Rack::Mime.mime_type('.json')
  parse_json
end
```

Notes:

- [`Rack::Mime.mime_type('.json')`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack%2FMime.mime_type) is a shortcut for `application/json`.
- `request.media_type` might be needed instead of `request.content_type` in some use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `request.content_type`?

But the response could be a plain text and still be a valid `JSON`, so I think it would be valid to get the contents and try to parse it.